# Click event on Google Notification

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am developing a google chrome extension for my website.

I want that when the user clicks on the desktop notification of google chrome, that my website opens.

So how can I handle the google chrome desktop notification click event?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Based on this: http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/notifications.html
I solved like this:

I made a notification.html file:

```
<html>
<head>
  <base target="_blank" />
</head>
<body>
  <a href="http://example.com">Open site</a>
</body>
</html>
```

And I open notification with this code:

```
var notification = webkitNotifications.createHTMLNotification(
    'notification.html'
);

notification.show();
```

You can CSS the  to look like a full link without text in notification body.

Comment: webkitNotifications.createHTMLNotification() isn't in the API any more.

Comment: If the API has been deprecated, couldn't the answer be updated instead of voting it down?

Answer (score 4):

If you don't want to use an HTML notification, you can add a click event handler to the notification and call the "cancel" function.

```
var notification = window.webkitNotifications.createNotification(
        'url', 'title', 'text');

notification.addEventListener('click', function() {
    notification.cancel();
    window.open('url')
})
notification.show();
```